# Get values from inputs, calculate them and show the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have these two text inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="width" name="width" />
<input type="text" value="" id="height" name="height" />
```

And below there is:

```
<h1>Summ: xxxxxx</h1>
```

I want to replace xxxxx with the following math:

```
(width * height) / 2
```

Whenever I type a new value at width or height inputs, the Summ should change realtime.

Is this possible at all?
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I just added some document.write code that I saw here and there on the internet, but nothing showed up.

Comment: if you try angular js https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="width" name="width" />
<input type="text" value="" id="height" name="height" />

<h1 class="calc"></h1>
```

And:

```
$('#width, #height').on('input', function () {
    var widthInput = $('#width').val()
    var heightInput = $('#height').val()
    var result = widthInput * heightInput / 2
    $('.calc').text(result)
})
```

You might wanna put a placeholder value like `1` for each field so it doesn't begin calculating with a 0. Also, it's spelled "sum" and not "summ", and it's not a sum anyway.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mLht98h8/1/)

Comment: The fiddle is working fine, but I cant get it to work on my page. I saw there's an "onLoad" at the fiddle site. Do i have to add anything else?

Comment: @dominotrix Only jQuery.

Comment: Oh, i had to change $ to jQuery. It's working great, thank you very very much for your help !!

Comment: @dominotrix I suggest not to repeat code like that. Also, You should verify if user input is valid and numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to do that. There are many technologies frameworks, libraries, and ways to do it.

In my case (as I'm more familiar with this), the easier would be to use JQuery like this.

```js
$('#width, #height').on('input', function(){
  var width = $('#width').val();
  var height = $('#height').val();
  
  if (width != "" && height != "")
      $('#result').text(width*height/2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="" id="width" name="width" />
<input type="number" value="" id="height" name="height" />

<h1>Result: <span id='result'>0</span></h1>
```

Obs: I changed your input fields to numeric type, so the user won't enter non-numeric data.

Comment: Do the user have to click out of the inputs to show the result?

Comment: @dominotrix, you can set a start value. I've just edited it to show what you wanted.

Comment: @dominotrix Just replace `input` with `keyup` if you want immediate calculation.

Comment: @Vidul keyup is good for cases like this, but input callback is more complete (it already changes the result instantly). If you change the callback from 'input' to 'keyup' on the snippet above, it won't work for the numeric input if you use the arrows up and down, for instance. Take a look.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes I didn't know this detail. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The main pieces of the problem are:

- How do I get the value of an input box?
- How do I execute code whenever input changes?
- How do I set the text of an element?

The relevant functions are [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/), and [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) respectively. The examples in the documentation should help you figure out how to piece it all together.

Comment: val() acts on any elements selected with the jquery selector--doesn't matter if it's selects, inputs, textarea, etc. In your example it would be $('#width').val()